# Bash: Converting 4 columns of text interleaved lines (tab-delimited columns to FASTQ file)

Tags: bash, awk, bioinformatics, fastq

I need to convert a 4-column file to 4 lines per entry. The file is tab-delimited.

The file at current is arranged in the following format, with each line representing one record/sequence (with millions of such lines):

```
@SRR1012345.1   NCAATATCGTGG    #4=DDFFFHDHH    HWI-ST823:136:C24YTACXX
@SRR1012346.1   GATTACAGATCT    #4=DDFFFHDHH    HWI-ST823:136:C22YTAGXX
```

I need to rearrange this such that the four columns are presented as 4 lines:

```
@SRR1012345.1
NCAATATCGTGG
#4=DDFFFHDHH
HWI-ST823:136:C24YTACXX
@SRR1012346.1
GATTACAGATCT
#4=DDFFFHDHH
HWI-ST823:136:C22YTAGXX
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this, preferably with a bash one-liner? Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: That's not a valid Fastq file

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tr`:

```
< file tr '\t' '\n' > newfile
```

Answer (score 2):

very clear to use awk here:

```
awk '{print $1; print $2; print $3; print $4}' file
```

Comment: @hek2mgl there shouldn't be `-f` option. now should work

Comment: Yeah, it works now! :) .. You could also use this: `awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' OFS='\n' file`. Btw, I don't think `awk` should be used here. If you want to *translate* one character by another character `tr` is the specialized tool for that. I guess it can do the job significantly faster than `awk` but I've not benchmarked it so far.

Comment: I've created an 1.3M test file that contains the records mentioned in the question multiple times. The mean time `awk` used over 1000 tries was 0.026 seconds while `tr` took just 0.008 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1' file
@SRR1012345.1
NCAATATCGTGG
#4=DDFFFHDHH
HWI-ST823:136:C24YTACXX
@SRR1012346.1
GATTACAGATCT
#4=DDFFFHDHH
HWI-ST823:136:C22YTAGXX
```